# Create copy of Azure SQL Database using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

When running the following query on an Azure SQL Database "Master" in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
CREATE DATABASE myDbBackup AS COPY OF myDb;
```

The following error is produced:

```
Msg 40818, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Operation on database 'myDb' failed because there are alter operations pending on the database. Try again after the pending operations have completed.
```

Any guidance on how to resolve this and end all alter operations that are pending so I can go through with the copy? There is only one other person using this DB and neither he nor I are running a query. I even went so far as to revoke the firewall permissions to the server.. not even this worked. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try reviewing DMVs [sys.dm_database_copies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270023.aspx) and [sys.dm_operations_status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270022(v=sql.120).aspx) which are Azure SQL Database-only, and meant for reviewing progress on these type of operations eg

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_operation_status

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_database_copies
```

Review the `state_desc` and `error_desc` columns.  Post the output here if required.

Comment: sys.dm_operation_status has `AAC670E5-0F17-4CB3-B05C-08CC135ED6F8 0 Database myDb FA789ED6-2480-47C1-B1FD-5CCEBC7EDA15 CREATE DATABASE COPY 3 FAILED 100 40818 Operation on database 'myDb' failed because there are alter operations pending on the database. Try again after the pending operations have completed. 16 0 2014-12-13 10:07:14.097 2014-12-13 10:07:31.280` and sys.dm_database_copies is empty.